# ffmpeg unknown keyword invalid data found when processing input

Tags: windows, powershell, ffmpeg

I have a file `ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt` with the content

```
file '.\Output_0\forces_vs_radii.pdf'
file '.\Output_1\forces_vs_radii.pdf'
file '.\Output_2\forces_vs_radii.pdf'
file '.\Output_3\forces_vs_radii.pdf'
file '.\Output_4\forces_vs_radii.pdf'
and so on...
```

and then run `ffmpeg -f concat -i ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt -c copy output.mkv` as is stated at

http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

I, unfortunately, get the error

```
Line 1: unknown keyword ' ■f'
.\ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

in Windows PowerShell in Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your input file has the wrong encoding (presumably UTF-16 LE). Run `(Get-Content 'ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt') | Set-Content 'ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt' -Encoding Ascii` to fix that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have no idea how you see / guessed that I have the wrong encoding, but your suggestion seems to help. Now, I have to fix the framerate, because `.\ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i .\ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt -c copy output.mkv -framerate 5` does not seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: The `' ■f'` in the error message is pretty much a dead giveaway.

Comment: Are you trying to turn a PDF into an image or video? FFmpeg does not have a PDF demuxer. Secondly, option placement matters, and trailing options are often ignored: `ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i [output options] output`. Thirdly, `-framerate` is an input option for certain demuxers: for output use `-r` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's an encoding problem I also got that I solved changing the file encoding.
Steps to solve it:

1. Open the ffmpeg_list_of_files.txt with the notepad, notepad++ or similar
2. Change the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM. To do it follow one of the next steps:

- with windows notepad, this is done using the "save as..." option and at the bottom changing the encoding to "UTF-8" and press "save"
- with notepad++ select "encoding" in the main menu and select "encoding with UTF-8 without BOM" and save the file after that

Names could change a little bit depending on the version, but following the steps it's pretty straight forward.

Note: In my case, when redirecting ls or dir to a file in powershell, the default encoding of the file is USC-2