# FFmpeg error when concatenate one base mp4 file + a bunch of MP4 files\

Tags: ffmpeg

unfortunately I am not good at coding whatsoever.

I want to concatenate a bunch of mp4 files with one so called video.mp4 file.
I have lots of different mp4 files which need to be merged with the so called video.mp4 file

This is written in my .bat file which i run with ffmpeg

`for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -f concat -i "%%i" -i "video.mp4" -c copy "%%~nfi_complete.mp4"`

when i run it it keeps giving me the error:
code line 4: unknown keyword 'ftypisom: invalid data found when processing input.

anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg unknown keyword invalid data found when processing input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926703/ffmpeg-unknown-keyword-invalid-data-found-when-processing-input)

Comment: I have the same issue; I get `unknown keyword 'ftypisom'`. I am not using a list of files so that other answer does not solve my problem. My command line is simply as follows: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 2021-01-04_14-02-20-168.mp4 -i 2021-01-04_14-19-52-492.mp4 -c copy a.mp4`